# How to fix Ansible error: conflicting action statements: include, topic

Tags: ansible

```
---

- name: Register topic
  include: registration.yml
  topic: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ kafka_topic }}"
```

When trying to run the playbook, the following error is shown:

> ERROR! conflicting action statements: include, topic The error appears
> to be in '/xxx/yyy/tasks/main.yml
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - name: Register topic

Answer (score 0):

`topic: X` is not a valid Ansible statement.

If I understand correctly, you want to pass in a variable named `topic` to the tasks file.

If so, this is the way to do it:

```
---
- name: Register topic
  include: registration.yml
  vars:
    topic: "{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ kafka_topic }}"
```

Where `kafka_topic` is a list / map of items.

Also, note that `with_items` is being deprecated and replaced by the [`loop`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops).

---

If you want to access the item with a diff name, try this

```
- name: Register topic
  include: registration.yml
  loop: "{{ kafka_topic }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: topic
```

Then in your registration.yml you can use the looped item as `{{ topic }}`

Comment: I think what I need to do is pass the kafka_topic variable to the registration.yml. But in registration.yml, there are multiple place holders for {{ topic }}. Do you have any example to show how I can use loop here?

Comment: Updated my answer to address that @KelvinHo